# [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, web, next-auth, next.js13

**I am trying to use next-auth with nextJS13.2 with new api routes**
**Expected**
Redirect to google signin page

**full error**

```
error - app/SignInComponent.tsx (14:15) @ values
error - TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.values (<anonymous>)
at SignInComponent (./app/SignInComponent.tsx:16:26)
12 |     <div>
13 |       {
> 14 |         Object.values(providers!).map((provider) => (
   |               ^
  15 |           <div key={provider.name}>
16 |             <button onClick={() => signIn()}>SignIn with       {provider.
name}</button>
17 |           </div>
```

nextjs -> 13.2.4
next-auth -> v4

**My app/api/[...nextauth]/route.ts :**

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
    })
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signIn"
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

**app/auth/signin/page.tsx**

```
import SignInComponent from "@/app/SignInComponent"
import {getProviders, signIn} from "next-auth/react"

async function SignInPage() {
  const providers = await getProviders()
  console.log(providers)
  return (
    <div>
      <SignInComponent providers={providers} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignInPage
```

**SignInComponent**

```
"use client"
import { getProviders, signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import React from 'react'

type Props = {
  providers: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getProviders>>
}

function SignInComponent({providers}: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        Object.values(providers! || {}).map((provider) => (
          <div key={provider.name}>
            <button onClick={() => signIn()}>
            SignIn with {provider.name}
            </button>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignInComponent
```

**.env.local**

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=***********
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=*************

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

SECRET=************
```

Comment: I'm using the same libraries and versions, and I'm getting the same issue with the same configuration.

Multiple posts state that adding `NEXTAUTH_URL` as an environment variable will help, but that has done nothing for me either.

Really interested to see if anyone has tractable suggestions or solutions for this.